# How to properly apply values farmed from .each()

Tags: jquery-ui

```
Markup:
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul id="ratx">
      <li>Location</li>
      <li class="bar"><span></span></li>
      <li class="value">4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul id="ratx">
     <li>Hotel Services</li>
     <li class="bar"><span></span></li>
     <li class="value">5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul id="ratx">
      <li>Hotel Facilities</li>
      <li class="bar"><span></span></li>
      <li class="value">3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul id="ratx">
      <li>Room Cleanliness</li>
      <li class="bar"><span></span></li>
      <li class="value">4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul id="ratx">
      <li>Value for Money</li>
      <li class="bar"><span></span></li>
      <li class="value">1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to represent User Ratings dynamically using JQuery so I made a function like this,

```
jQuery:
$("ul#ratx").each(function(index) {
var val = $(this).children(".value").text();
var barval = val * 40;

/* compute ratings */ 
$("li.bar span").css("width", barval);

});
```

Now, when I alert *barval* I get all 5 values but when I try to apply the "compute ratings" line, all it does is apply the last value that it finds. How should I go about this?

Sorry if the question is a confusing. I am not quite sure how to phrase everything.

Comment: You'd better attach the related lines in your HTML to help people understand your question.

Comment: Show the markup that goes along with this piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, while interating through each elements it find, it is applying a common value to all `li.bar span`. You should represent a single element, you are trying to apply to.

> <strike>$(this).children("li.bar span").css("width", barval);</strike>

#### Update

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/hMrtP/1/) is a working Demo

The snippet that worked was

```
$(this).find("li.bar").children("span").css("width", barVal );
```

Also, I changed the display property of the span to `display: inline-block;`

Comment: I tried that before, but I don't think **bold$(this).children("li.bar span")** is accepted as correct because it doesn't compute for me.

Comment: @Morningseven, Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your code. I would be happy to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the css for **all the elements** in the set `$("li.bar span")`. So at the end, they all have the same width of the last parsed value.

Without seeing you markup, it's difficult to propose you a code solution though.